# I am trying to write dijkstras algorithm however i am stuck as I am getting an error because i think it searches out of the bounds of the array

Tags: python, arrays, dijkstra

Here is the code i have wrote any idea what is wrong?

```
import numpy as np

# The 7 by 7 grid provided. X is the starting square,
# _ represents a square, Y is the finishing square
# and Z is an obstacle.
Maze = np.array([
    "X", "_", "_", "_", "_", "Z", "_",
    "_", "Z", "Z", "Z", "_", "_", "_",
    "_", "Z", "_", "_", "_", "_", "Z",
    "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_",
    "_", "_", "Z", "_", "Z", "Z", "_",
    "_", "_", "Z", "_", "Z", "_", "_",
    "_", "_", "Z", "_", "_", "_", "Y"
])

CurrentValue = "Y"

# If not on the starting square, the robot will move to
# a new square and check if it is an obstacle or a new 
# square.
while CurrentValue != "X":
    currentCoords = np.argwhere(Maze == CurrentValue)
    #print("Current Coordinates:", currentCoords[-1])

    RightCoords = {6, 13, 20, 27, 34, 41, 48}

    if currentCoords == RightCoords:
        pass


    # If the new square is an empty space, mark it as the current value + 1.
    print(Maze[tuple(currentCoords[-1])])
    if Maze[tuple(currentCoords[-1])] == "_":

        Maze[tuple(currentCoords[-1])] = str(int(CurrentValue) + 1)
    elif Maze[tuple(currentCoords[-1])] == "X":
        print("Maze:", Maze)
        CurrentValue = "X"

    #print("Current Value:", CurrentValue)

    
    # Move to the left and update the current value accordingly.
    #currentCoords[-1][1] = 1

# The while loop ends when the robot reaches the starting square "Y".
#print("Maze:", Maze)
```

Any idea on how to fix this error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Retake\code\Dijkstra\maze.py", line 27, in <module>
    neighbors.append((currentCoords[0, 0] - 1, currentCoords[0, 1]))
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1
PS C:\Users\User\Retake>
```

All help appreciated thank you:)

I have tried changing the values in the line but it comes up with almost the same thing.

Comment: You haven't included the code where the error occurs. The error message mentions  `neighbors.append()`, but the code block in your question does not have that statement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's because your numpy array is 1D. So you can't use double indexing, i.e. `currentCoords[0][0]` or `currentCoords[0, 0]`. You could, perhaps, perform the computation to figure out where that 2D Coordinate would be in a 1D array. A better method might be to convert it to a 2D array like so:

```
Maze = np.array([
    "X", "_", "_", "_", "_", "Z", "_",
    "_", "Z", "Z", "Z", "_", "_", "_",
    "_", "Z", "_", "_", "_", "_", "Z",
    "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_",
    "_", "_", "Z", "_", "Z", "Z", "_",
    "_", "_", "Z", "_", "Z", "_", "_",
    "_", "_", "Z", "_", "_", "_", "Y"
])

# Reshape the 1D array into a 2D 7x7 grid
Maze = Maze.reshape((7, 7))
```

Alternatively, you can initialize it as a 2D Array like this:

```
Maze = np.array([
    ["X", "_", "_", "_", "_", "Z", "_"],
    ["_", "Z", "Z", "Z", "_", "_", "_"],
    ["_", "Z", "_", "_", "_", "_", "Z"],
    ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"],
    ["_", "_", "Z", "_", "Z", "Z", "_"],
    ["_", "_", "Z", "_", "Z", "_", "_"],
    ["_", "_", "Z", "_", "_", "_", "Y"]
])
```